# Issues with homebrew tap and cask

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am trying to set up my own Homebrew tap for casks which aren't available on the official Hombrew tap. I am getting a `Error: Cannot tap depal1/gamezz: invalid syntax in tap!` and "invalid formula" errors on my casks when I try to install them through either `brew install`  or `brew install --cask`.

I have checked the Homebrew documentation, and I haven't found these errors.

```
user@Mac ~ % brew install Depal1/gamezz/eliot 
==> Tapping depal1/gamezz
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/depal1/homebrew-gamezz'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 34, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Total 34 (delta 17), reused 21 (delta 9), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (34/34), 4.87 KiB | 4.87 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17/17), done.
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/depal1/homebrew-gamezz/heroic.rb
heroic: undefined method `cask' for Formulary::FormulaNamespace4614367febee3ececbe1e037717b6581:Module
Did you mean?  case
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/depal1/homebrew-gamezz/alpha.rb
alpha: undefined method `cask' for Formulary::FormulaNamespace768a6fe31cc4288c1aec82563e762fbc:Module
Did you mean?  case
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/depal1/homebrew-gamezz/eliot.rb
eliot: undefined method `cask' for Formulary::FormulaNamespacef6d6268ad500b3243a6c7d291d6d159f:Module
Did you mean?  case
Error: Cannot tap depal1/gamezz: invalid syntax in tap!
```

The homebrew tap is hosted at https://github.com/Depal1/homebrew-gamezz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in the cask itself but according to the [documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap#casks) you have to:

> Place any cask files you wish to make available in a Casks directory at the top level of your tap.

Such as in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask